# A space $X$ with property that all compact subspaces are closed.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

> If all **compact subspaces** of $X$ are **closed** in $X$, then is $X$ **Hausdorff** ? If not then please give counter-example.

We know that converse is true i.e. compact subspace of Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: They are called [$T_B$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513921/a-topological-space-is-called-t-b-if) or $KC$ spaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer I feel they need not be Hausdorff, but I have not been able to produce any counterexample.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955382/spaces-where-all-compact-subsets-are-closed) may help. I think constructing a non-Hausdorff example is nontrivial.

Comment: Actually, [it's not so hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530638/compactness-and-hausdorffness).